# Using a Source block as the key in a collection

Tags: anylogic

I'm want to create a collection that will use my source blocks (there are many) as the key element to lookup a value. I want to use this collection as part of a inject function that will use the source name to get the value I need.
I'm wondering it will look like this:
int injectfunction = collectionName.get(SourceBlockName);

I'm open to hear about other more efficient methods.

I've tried using a LinkedHashMap with a Key element class "Other" then specified it as "Source" and the value element as int. I also tried Source, but in both cases it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

create a collection of type LinkedHashMap with key type String and value element class Source

Then you can populate your collection using this for example:

```
for(Object o : findAll(getEmbeddedObjects(),o->o instanceof Source)){
    collection.put(((Source)o).getName(),(Source)o);
}
```

Then you can just use the name of the source to inject:

```
collection.get("source name").inject();
```